# How to interrupt a synchronized method that is blocked

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have an Object with a synchronized method:

```
public class Foo {
    public synchronized void bar() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And I have thousands of threads calling the same method. When I want to quit the program, how can I interrupt these waiting threads so that the program exits immediately?

I have tried to call `Thread.interrupt()` and `Foo.notify()` but not work.

The question is:
Is blocking synchronized method interruptible?

Comment: [This](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_interruption_2.shtml) should help

Comment: Don't do anything blocking inside the method, or else make the blocking action interruptible somehow.

Comment: If you have thousands of threads, that's a sign that threads are not a good design choice here.

Comment: This must be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is blocking synchronized method interruptible? **NO**
,but below is the best way to achieve what you wanted to do!

```
public class Foo {
    private final  Lock lock  = new ReentrantLock();
    public void bar() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
          // Do stuff
        }finally {
           lock.unlock()
        }
    }
}
```

Please use java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock for 
this purpose. From Java doc of lockInterruptibly method

```
/**
     * Acquires the lock unless the current thread is
     * {@linkplain Thread#interrupt interrupted}.
     *
     * <p>Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately.
     *
     * <p>If the lock is not available then the current thread becomes
     * disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until
     * one of two things happens:
     *
     * <ul>
     * <li>The lock is acquired by the current thread; or
     * <li>Some other thread {@linkplain Thread#interrupt interrupts} the
     * current thread, and interruption of lock acquisition is supported.
     * </ul>
     *
     * <p>If the current thread:
     * <ul>
     * <li>has its interrupted status set on entry to this method; or
     * <li>is {@linkplain Thread#interrupt interrupted} while acquiring the
     * lock, and interruption of lock acquisition is supported,
     * </ul>
     * then {@link InterruptedException} is thrown and the current thread's
     * interrupted status is cleared.
```

Reference : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly%28%29

Answer (score 2):

You must design the thread to respond properly to an interruption. Unless the thread is checking for one, it won't do anything when interrupt() is called. There is a good explanation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html